# Project wont build in flash develop cant figure out why

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flashdevelop

i am getting these errors when trying build a project in flash develop i was wondering if anyone could help me

- C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(63):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(7):
  col: 11 Error: Definition gs:TweenLite could not be found.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(94):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(93):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(92):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(91):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(91):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(89):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(88):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(68):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(67):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(66):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(65):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(64):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(63):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
  C:\flash\Projects\FM104\Audio Player\src\EqualizerAnimation.as(62):
  col: 4 Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.

here is now Equalizer Animation action script file bearing in mind i have zero flash skills we have lost our flash developers

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    import gs.TweenLite;
    import gs.easing.*;

    /**
     * Controls the equalizer animation
     * @author FM104 
     */
    public class EqualizerAnimation
    {

        private var eq:MovieClip;
        private var eqTimer:Timer;


        public function EqualizerAnimation():void
        {
            eq = Main.instance.player.Eq; 
        }


        /**
         * start timer
         * @param
         * @return void
         */
        public function start():void
        {
            eqTimer = new Timer(100, 0);
            eqTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startAnimation);
            eqTimer.start();
        }


        /**
         * stop
         * @param
         * @return void
         */
        public function stop():void
        {
            try {
                eqTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startAnimation);
                eqTimer.stop();
                stopAnimation();
            } catch (err:Error) {}
        }


        /**
         * animate the eq bars
         * @param   evt
         * @return void
         */
        private function startAnimation(evt:TimerEvent):void
        {
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar1, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar2, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar3, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar4, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar5, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar6, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar7, 0.1, { height:( Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1)) + 10 ) } );
        }


        /**
         * stop animating
         * @param
         * @return void
         */
        private function stopAnimation():void
        {
            /*
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar1, 0, { height:30 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar2, 0, { height:30 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar3, 0, { height:30 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar4, 0, { height:30 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar5, 0, { height:30 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar6, 0, { height:30 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar7, 0, { height:30 } );
            */
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar1, 1, { height:1 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar2, 1, { height:1 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar3, 1, { height:1 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar4, 1, { height:1 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar5, 1, { height:1 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar6, 1, { height:1 } );
            TweenLite.to( eq.Bar7, 1, { height:1 } );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Obviously, you haven't set up the dependency for TweenLite correctly. That's an external library you program needs to run. You should hire someone to do this for you - what you're doing is a bit like driving a truck without a license.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have the resources to do so...

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you need to add the TweenLite library. There are instructions on the TweenLite website: http://www.greensock.com/get-started-tweening/#installing

From your code, it looks like an older version of TweenLite was used so you'll have to change all import statements that start with "gs", eg:

```
import gs.TweenLite;
import gs.easing.*;
```

To com.greensock:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
```